# Faithful representation of degree 1 of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ - only exist for n \leqslant 2?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, representation-theory

I have a homework question: show that $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$ has a faithful representation of degree 1 over $\mathbb{R}$ iff $n \leqslant 2$. I'm currently working on showing if $n = 1, 2$, then there is a representation.

My problem is that isn't

$$ \rho : \mathbb{Z}_n \to \text{GL}(1, \mathbb{R}) = (\mathbb{R}, +)  \\  [x] \mapsto x \text{ (mod n)} $$

an injective homomorphism (so faithful representation of degree 1 over $\mathbb{R}$) for *any* $n$ ?

I can prove it's a homomorphism by $([a]  + [b])\rho = [a + b]\rho = (a + b) \text{ (mod n)} = a\text{ (mod n)} + b\text{ (mod n)} = [a]\rho + [b]\rho$

And it's injective by; if $[a]\rho = a \text{ (mod n)} = b \text{ (mod n)} = [b]\rho $, then $[a] = [b]$ because $[a] = [b]$ iff $a = b \text{ (mod n)}$.

I didn't rely on $n \leqslant 2$ in any way. I can't figure out where I went wrong though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Recall that $\text{GL}(1,\mathbb R)=(\mathbb R,\cdot)$.

Comment: ahh damn, that's true. Thank you!